Access DBF 2 table query to show on form last promotion date and rank
I been working on a form that I need to show  only the last date and rank everyone has had over the years they have worked.
In the "emplmain" table I been using the DOH date/time field with the "emplpromotd" table date/time field with holds all the promotions done over the years.
Not much experience in wring SQL code out of design and could use some direction on how I can something to work.
Thanks
I need to show a persons information gathered in the 2 tables with the current rank and title changes that is held in the emppromotd table and all employee information that is held in the emplymain table.
I have a query running now that they can lookup the empolyee by their name and ID number but, I having problems with their last rank showing.

You should sow data examples for  booth  tables and desired output.

This question is similar to: Select only the latest version of each record based on date | MS Access. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you want this form to allow data entry/edit?
